# How to show specific element in table cells using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Based on my searches when you want to hide the visibility of element in html using angularjs just used ng-show or ng-hide. In my page I have a table generated using ng-repeat.Each row have a button "show check". When  the button is clicked the word "CHECK" should display beside the ID. Ng-show is working fine except when I clicked the button in the row with ID 1 all the rows display CHECK the, CHECK word should be display only in a row where I have click the button. What is missing? I try to passed the key parameter but it's not work. Any advice and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

My fiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/wydyagao/

I used this code so far:

```
$scope.myVar = true;
$scope.toggleShow = function(key){
  alert(key);
  $scope.myVar =!$scope.myVar;
};
```

Comment: you should bind `myVar` for each row instead of using the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `myVar` for each user in the `ng-repeat` list.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td><p ng-show ="user.myVar">CHECK</p>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.stat}}</td>
            <td><button id ="btn" ng-click = "toggleShow(user)">show check</button>                  </td>
</tr>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.toggleShow = function(user){
  alert(user.myVar);
  user.myVar =!user.myVar;
};
```

Comment: what if I will change the "CHECK" word to image. . Can binding still works?

Comment: yes of coz. `ng-if` directive can work on all elements, no matter it's `div`, `img` or plain text.

Comment: Can you update jsfiddle for trouble shooting? This error doesn't appear from my side

Comment: Hey @Rebornix. Thank you very much, I am transferring the code to my real project and forgot to change some variables. Your code is working fine thanks again.